# A non-arithmetical set?

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability

A set is called [arithmetical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_set) if it can be defined by a first-order formula in Peano arithmetic.  I first encountered these sets when exploring the arithmetical hierarchy in the context of computability theory.  However, I have not encountered any examples of sets that are not arithmetical.

Is there a canonical example of an non-arithmetical set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are countably many first order formulas defining arithmetical sets.
Let $\varphi_n$, $n\in\mathbb N$, be a list of those.
Consider the set that contains a natural number $n$ iff $n$ is not contained
in the set defined by the $n$-th formula.

Comment: Gotcha.  I completely forgot you could diagonalize.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

One example is the set of Gödel numbers for all true arithmetic sentences. If this was arithmetical, then [Berry's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox) could be formalized and yield a contradiction.

Comment: Note: this is [Tarski's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_undefinability_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

The usual examples are things like:

$0^{\omega}$ or anything bigger.
Any arithmetically generic set.
The set of ordinal notations or equivalently the indexes for computable well-orderings or even the indexes of well-founded computable trees.

I figured I'd add these because these are natural examples not merely a diagonalization.

Though the godel numbers of true statements of arithmetic is quite natural.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $0^\omega$.  Do you have a reference on where I could learn more about it?

Comment: I think Peter might mean what's usually designated $0^{(\omega)}$, the $\omega$-th Turing Jump (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump) of a computable set.

Comment: Yah, sorry for being sloppy...I have macros to do that for me.

If you still want a reference try Classical Recursion Theory Vol 2

More simply it's just $\oplus_{i \in \omega} 0^{(i)}$