# An example of a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that is used in number theory but cannot be written in terms of Peano arithmetic.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, peano-axioms

I would like to know an example showing that second-order mathematical induction is stronger than first-order mathematical induction.

For a condition $P(x)$ that can be written in the language of Peano arithmetic, we can construct the set $\{x\in\mathbb{N};P(x)\}$.

Which subset of $\mathbb{N}$ cannot be constructed this way?

---

The examples in the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163035/a-non-arithmetical-set) suggested as a duplicate are not what I expected.

I would like to know an example that is actually used in number theory, not ones that are only used as counterexamples.

Here, "actually used in number theory" is defined as being written in an article published in the [Journal of Number Theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_of_Number_Theory).

Comment: I think your modified question may be a bit too broad/vague - what do you mean by "actually used in number theory"? Depending on how much number theory you know, it's likely that most/all of it can be carried out in PA. The family of arithmetical sets is a **huge** superset of the family of computable sets, and you might already protest that most/all non-computable sets are too "counterexample"-y. Can you give an example of a non-computable set that suits your taste, so answerers know roughly what they're aiming for?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen You claim that this question is a duplicate. Which theorem in number theory would you use the linked examples to prove?

Comment: I am skeptical that close-voters and reviewers can point me to the Journal of Number Theory article containing those answers.

Comment: Hello. I never claimed that those answers have anything to do with number theory. I voted to close [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4886034/1) revision as a dupe, which didn't mention number theory at all, and my previous comment was written before you started talking about the JNT. I agree that this version of the post is not a dupe of that question. Do you know if there's reason to believe there is such a set? As I say, many non-computable sets already feel artificial. If you don't know any non-computable example, maybe you could ask that first/too?

Comment: If you have a strong reason to believe that there is a set of the type you're asking about, it could also help if you write why that's the case. I'm sorry if it comes across like I/others are picking on you. I am really trying to help you to get an answer to your question! I can only speculate on why others have voted to not reopen. Possibly some people feel it's now too subjective/imprecise/uninteresting, or they feel like you're a bit standoffish and "moving the goalposts" which makes them unsympathetic. I don't agree and I'll vote to reopen but it's not just up to me!